# Grails 2.3 strange plug-in eager loading behavior

Tags: spring, grails

I've just added a custom local plug-in (via 'grails.plugin.location...' build config declaration) to a grails 2.3 project.  As soon as I add the plug-in and try to run my application I see a strange behavior whereby all of the beans in my main application suddenly try to eagerload across the board.  I.e. if I have:

```
class FooService {
  BarService barService
}

class BarService {
  FooService fooService
}
```

Then the application cannot start. There is no code being executed in FooService or BarService at init time that should cause the Spring context to need to unwrap the either fooService or barService instance but that behavior seems to be happening anyway.  In the end the application init fails with an exception like:

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fooService': org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBeanNotInitializedException: FactoryBean is not fully initialized yet

As the fooService requires the barService, which requires the fooService which is still being created.

As soon as I remove the dependency on the custom plug-in then the problem stops.  Obviously something either in the plugin or about the plugin (meta data or something) is causing this behavior but I can't figure out what exactly.

Rather than a solution I think what I am looking for here is some trouble-shooting techniques or information leading me to understand why this eagerloading behavior is occurring.  I just don't know what the right hooks/configs are that will let me get in the head of the Spring context initialization mechanism.

Comment: Are these services split between the plugin and the application? E.g. FooService is inside the plugin and the BarService is in the application? Or are they both in the application or both in the plugin?

Comment: These services are both in the main application so by simply adding the plugin the behavior of the main application is being altered.  As a further note there is nothing in the stack trace indicating that a particular call to something like grailsApplication.mainContext.getBeansOfType() or something like that is initiating this eager load.

Comment: I wouldn't do it that way. Here you have a dreaded circular dependency, which should be avoided

Comment: Spring is designed to allow for cyclical application context graphs as long as there is not a circular dependency in the initialization code of a given bean.  I don't have any such code.  Anyone out there have any idea how to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question buried deep in the comments of this other SO question: [Grails service using a method from another service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212072/grails-service-using-a-method-from-another-service)

Basically my plugin introduced the hibernate plug-in into my project and therefore also introduced transactional-by-default services.  This transactional bootstrapping was causing the eager load of all dependencies and thus my circular dependency problem.

The fix was to, at least for now, mark the circularly dependent services as non-transactional.  Of course in the future if I need those services to be transactional it seems I will need to re-architect my service setup.